# Corollaries of the halo conjecture that do not involve the eigencurve

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, congruences

In the theory of p-adic modular forms there is a certain construction called the Coleman-Mazur eigencurve. The spectral halo conjecture roughly states that if you remove a closed subdisc of the weight space, the eigencurve is an infinite disjoint union of finite flat covers of what remains of the weight space.

For a person who does not intrinsically care about the eigencurve, what interest does the halo conjecture pose? What corollaries does it have that do not directly involve the eigencurve?

Answer (score 3):

There was just a paper posted by Newton and Thorne (https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11261) on automorphy of symmetric powers of eigenforms that might be something you care about. See also a recent blog post here: https://www.galoisrepresentations.com/2019/12/30/new-results-in-modularity-christmas-update-ii/.

Of course, you might also not care about that thing. Perhaps someone can answer you more usefully if you describe more carefully what you actually care about?

Comment: how is the halo conjecture relevant to the arguments described in the paper? Would the theorem be easier (or harder) to prove if it were true?

Comment: to be more precise: the halo conjecture is not directly mentioned in the paper. A description of the eigencurve in some specific case by Buzzard and Kilford is mentioned but that is too specific in my view.

Comment: The theorem of Buzzard & Kilford is one of the few known cases of the halo conjecture. So while I agree that the halo conjecture is not directly mentioned, it needn't be because the authors only need one specific case of the conjecture, the one proven by Bzuzard & Kilford, to pull off their argument. (I'll add that there is a lot of other mathematics in this paper, all very interesting. The automorphy is reduced to special cases using the halo structure, but those special cases are themselves a big thing.)